# Primefaces p:poll update selector for class

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am doing Primefaces poller and I would like to select multiple items with Styleclass="updateable" inside the form. What would be the correct update selector for p:poll in this case? I need only to update parts of the form when the poll is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
<p:poll interval="3"  listener="#{myBean.myMethod}" update="@(.updateable)" />
```

Also take a look at the showcase: [PrimeFaces Selectors - @(selector)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf)

> PFS does not use findComponent() of UIComponent. It finds the components at client side so **it still needs an id to sent to server** to mark which components to update so you also need to give an id to components who you select with PFS although you are not reference these ids yourself. JSF impls do not render autogenerated clientIds to keep page size smaller if you don't give an explicit id. (Cagatay Civici)

Comment: That seems to work only when each updateable class has unique id defined as it uses findComponent function which returns the id of the component. Is there any other way than specifying the unique id for all components in this case? Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: PFS does not use findComponent() of UIComponent. It finds the components at client side so it still needs an id to sent to server to mark which components to update so you also need to give an id to components who you select with PFS although you are not reference these ids yourself. JSF impls do not render autogenerated clientIds to keep page size smaller if you don't give an explicit id.